# Catching Failed Synchronous HTTP Request

Tags: javascript

In my testing it seems if a synchronous query doesn't reach the server, it causes the browser to freeze.  Is it possible to handle this better?  I don't think the following is working properly (its hard to test this)

```
try { xmlHttp.send(null); }
catch (e) { 
 alert('Can you please try again? The last request did not go through properly.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `xmlHttpRequest` object does not throw an error for everything, it sets the status/statusText with the error code from the server.

Using a synchronous call is normally bad practice because of the browser locking up.